# The color of page number doesn't change in Beamer

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I cannot change the color of the page number at right bottom.
The setting applied to black but still be white, why?

How can I change the one to black??

```
¥documentclass[dvipdfmx,11pt,notheorems]{beamer}
¥usetheme{Madrid}
¥usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
¥setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][left]
¥setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
¥setbeamercovered{transparent}

% Footer
¥setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]
¥setbeamerfont{footline}{size=¥normalsize, series=¥bfseries}
¥setbeamercolor{footline}{fg = black, bg = black} 

¥usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
¥usepackage{amsthm}
¥usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
¥usepackage{textcomp}%
¥usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
¥usepackage{otf}%
¥usepackage{helvet}%

¥begin{document}

¥begin{frame}¥frametitle{test}
¥begin{block}{aaa}
¥begin{itemize}
¥item aaa
¥item bbb
¥end{itemize}
¥end{block}

¥begin{exampleblock}{Example}
¥begin{equation*}
¥frac{¥pi}{2} =¥left( ¥int_{0}^{¥infty} ¥frac{¥sin x}{¥sqrt{x}} dx ¥right)^2 =¥sum_{k=0}^{¥infty} ¥frac{(2k)!}{2^{2k}(k!)^2} ¥frac{1}{2k+1}
=¥prod_{k=1}^{¥infty} ¥frac{4k^2}{4k^2 - 1}
¥end{equation*}
¥end{exampleblock}

¥begin{exampleblock}{Example}
¥begin{equation*}
¥frac{¥pi}{2} =¥left( ¥int_{0}^{¥infty} ¥frac{¥sin x}{¥sqrt{x}} dx 
¥right)^2 =¥sum_{k=0}^{¥infty} ¥frac{(2k)!}{2^{2k}(k!)^2} ¥frac{1}{2k+1}
=¥prod_{k=1}^{¥infty} ¥frac{4k^2}{4k^2 - 1}
¥end{equation*}
¥end{exampleblock}

¥begin{exampleblock}{Example}
¥begin{equation*}
¥frac{¥pi}{2} =¥left( ¥int_{0}^{¥infty} ¥frac{¥sin x}{¥sqrt{x}} dx ¥right)^2 =¥sum_{k=0}^{¥infty} ¥frac{(2k)!}{2^{2k}(k!)^2} ¥frac{1}{2k+1}
=¥prod_{k=1}^{¥infty} ¥frac{4k^2}{4k^2 - 1}
¥end{equation*}
¥end{exampleblock}

¥end{frame}


¥end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been fixed in the development version of beamer with the commit https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/6fb90df75765a153492b240a5e325a7a761675be

A workaround for versions <= 3.50:

```
\documentclass[11pt,notheorems]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]
\setbeamerfont{footline}{size=\normalsize, series=\bfseries}
\setbeamercolor{footline}{fg = black, bg = black} 
\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{fg=black}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```